# What causes this dependency error in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I now get the following:

```
`dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- require_relative (LoadError`)
```

But I don't have enough information to figure out what is causing it or how to debug it.

What can I do?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you on?

Comment: I am not sure what caused it...all of the sudden, with some minor changes, I started to get this and I have no idea where to begin to fix it....when I create a brand new rails app instance, it starts fine, but I don't want to start from scratch.... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably comes from `linecache gem version 0.45` which was released yesterday. Rolling back to `0.43` will get you around this for now. I'm not sure if they intentionally broke support with Ruby 1.8.7 or not.

This is a dependency of `ruby-debug-base`.

Add something similar to the following in your `Gemfile`.

```
group :development, :test, :cucumber do 
  gem "linecache", "0.43"
  gem "ruby-debug-base", "0.10.4.0"
  gem "ruby-debug", "0.10.4"
end
```

Comment: ah, you are genius, that sounds like what it was, but am trying it now!  if this works, you saved my life

Comment: wow we just got this and i had a feeling it was linecache mucking up. i just didn'w know how to fix it. thanks for this! you saved two lives today

Comment: had the same problem this morning, and the above helped me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, add

```
gem 'require_relative'
```

to your Gemfile. It looks like linecache 0.45 needs it, but 0.43 doesn't, which is why downgrading linecache works.

Comment: I left this out of my answer, because I'm not sure what the intention of the 0.45 release of linecache is. It should have this dependency listed, or at least a note that it's broken with 1.8.7. For that reason, I don't trust this release and would rather wait for clarification or 0.46.

Comment: [Release 0.46](https://rubygems.org/gems/linecache) is available and now has a dependency for require_relative. Sorry for the omission.